# Java Steam login is not working

Tags: java, authentication, web, htmlunit

I am currently using the WebClient in the Gargoylesoftware package and Apache Commons stuff..

I'm trying to login to Steam via a Javabased WebClient. For whatever reason, this damn site NEVER lets me login!

Can anyone point me in the right direction? My code is below:

```
public void doLogin(){

    System.out.println("Grabbing first page..");
    HtmlPage loginPage;

    try {
        javabasedWebClient.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        javabasedWebClient.setRedirectEnabled(true);

        yummy = new CookieManager();
        javabasedWebClient.setCookieManager(yummy);

        yummy.setCookiesEnabled(true);

        loginPage = javabasedWebClient.getPage("https://store.steampowered.com/login/");

        System.out.println("Got the page!");

        // Setup the User
        final HtmlTextInput user = loginPage.getHtmlElementById("steamAccountName");
        user.setText("user");
        System.out.println(user.getText());

        // Setup the password
        final HtmlPasswordInput word = loginPage.getHtmlElementById("steamPassword");
        word.setText("password");
        System.out.println(word.getText());

        HtmlPage test = loginPage.getHtmlElementById("imageLogin").click();

        String[] itemPageCode = test1.asXml().split("\n");


        for (int i=0;i<itemPageCode.length;i++){

            System.out.println(itemPageCode[i]);
        }
        checkLoggedIn(itemPageCode);


    } catch (FailingHttpStatusCodeException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       


}
```

Comment: You are not setting the characters those appear in the image for validation.

Comment: No CATPCHA actually appears, that just Javascript on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. For some reason, if I basically do this function TWICE it then logs in correctly. Why? I have no idea O_o